# Div size inside jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, size

I've got some problems with setting width+height of divs A and B (content of them are generated with javascript). Size of that divs depends, which tab is selected when refreshing the page (selected tab has proper size). How to make it more stable?

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs" style="width:100%;margin:auto;clear:both;padding:auto;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs_0">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs_1">B</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs_0" class="subTab">
     <div id="A" style="height: 80%; width: 80%; margin: auto;"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs_1" class="subTab">
      <div id="B" style="height: 45%; width: 45%; margin: auto;></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here is apice of code that could help you:

```
     $(function() {
         $("#tabs").tabs();
         $("#tabs li a").click(function(){
             var id = $(this).attr('href');
             $(id).css({'height':'200px'})
             $(id).css({'width': '700px'})
         })
    });
```

Also you can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/aaa_borza/3eC9m/9/